# A site for general Tech Support

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Sorry if I've missed it somewhere, but is there a StackExchange site anywhere for just general Windows tech support?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Super User](http://superuser.com) is the site you want:

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a
>   question about ...
>
> - computer hardware,
> - computer software, or
> - personal and home computer networking

Comment: This Meta Q&A is currently the first Google hit for  `corporate IT support stackexchange`, which is expressly off-topic on Superuser.